# Angular Tour directive issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used below tour directive.

```
<tour step="currentStep" 
                    <span tourtip="Few more steps to go."
                          tourtip-next-label="Close"
                          tourtip-placement="bottom"
                          tourtip-offset="80"
                          tourtip-step="0">
                    </span>
</tour>
```

This is the [Tour Directive](https://github.com/DaftMonk/angular-tour)

Q 1: How can I make the whole item click able ? In other words if user clicks ,it should open a popup or something like that.

Q 2: Clicking anywhere on the page should close the tour item if it is open ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ng-click

Comment: @Madhu Yes,But when I use it,it opens the pop up when I click on x button also ?

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `div` and putting an `ng-click` on the `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize the `ng-if` directive in collaboration with custom directive (I've called it toggler) which will set the value on which `ng-if` depends accordingly to your needs, for example:

```
<tour toggler step="currentStep" 
    <span ng-if="open" tourtip="Few more steps to go."
        tourtip-next-label="Close"
        tourtip-placement="bottom"
        tourtip-offset="80"
        tourtip-step="0">
    </span> 
</tour>
```

When someone click on the `tour` element the `toggler` directive will set the `open` value to `true` and when someone clicks anywhere besides the `tour` element the `open` value will be set to `false` making the `ng-if` directive hide the element.
Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLzMjgmtkDjvqlxV1OT1?p=preview) with the implementation.